# Using openstreetmap on webpage

Tags: javascript, gis

Does anyone know if OpenStreetMap has some facility whereby I can provide a list of countries and the 'plugin' simply highlight the countries on the map?

Believe me, I've searched high and low over the last day or two, looking for examples, but can only see examples that provide highlights of specific Lat/Lon.

Appreciate this isn't really a 'development' question as such, but I'm positive someone somewhere on here has done something liket this.

Answer (score 1):

It supposes to use OpenLayers framework to load OpenSreetMap tiles.
This answer is based on openlayers examples.
Country contours information can be loaded from here:
//openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson

```js
var styleCache = {};
var countrySource = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
  projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  url: "http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson"
})
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: countrySource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
    if (!styleCache[text]) {
      styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#319FD3',
          width: 1
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          text: text,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 3
          })
        })
      })];
    }
    return styleCache[text];
  }
});

var view = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
  zoom: 5
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
        layer: 'osm'
      })
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});

var highlightStyleCache = {};

var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  map: map,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
    if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
      highlightStyleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#f00',
          width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          text: text,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#f00',
            width: 3
          })
        })
      })];
    }
    return highlightStyleCache[text];
  }
});

var highlight;
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });
  if (feature !== highlight) {
    if (highlight) {
      featureOverlay.removeFeature(highlight);
    }
    if (feature) {
      featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
    }
    highlight = feature;
  }
};

var selectFeatureInfo = function(featureId) {
  var features = countrySource.getFeatures();
  var feature;
  for (var f = 0; f < features.length; f++) {
    feature = features[f];
    if (feature.aa == featureId) {
      var polygon = (feature.getGeometry());
      var size = (map.getSize());
      view.fitGeometry(
        polygon,
        size, {
          padding: [170, 50, 30, 150]
        });
      break;
    }
  }
  if (feature !== highlight) {
    if (highlight) {
      featureOverlay.removeFeature(highlight);
    }
    if (feature) {
      featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
    }
    highlight = feature;
  }
};


$(map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
});

///
$(document).ready(function() {

  loadCountryJson();
  var countrySelector = document.getElementById('osm-country-selector');
  $(countrySelector).on('change', function() {
    selectFeatureInfo(this.value);
  });
});

function loadCountryJson() {

  $.getJSON("http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson", function(data) {

    var countryList = getCountries(data);
    var tools = document.getElementById('tools');
    $(tools).append('<select id="osm-country-selector"/>');
    var countrySelect = document.getElementById('osm-country-selector');
    $(countrySelect).attr("name", "countries");

    countryList.forEach(function(d) {
      $('#osm-country-selector').append($('<option>', {
        value: d.id,
        text: d.properties.name
      }));
    });
    $(countrySelect).on('change', function() {
      console.log('countrySelect');
      selectFeatureInfo(this.value);
    });

  });
}

function getCountries(data) {
  var i;
  var features = data.features;
  var items = [];
  for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    var country = features[i];
    var prop = country.properties;
    items.push({
      "id": country.id,
      "name": prop.name
    });
  }
  return features;
}
```

```css
.map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.4.0/ol.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<br/>
<div id="tools" />
```

To achive this task in following steps:

1. Provide html tags:

```html
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<br/>
<div id="tools" />
```

2. Initialize map:

```
var styleCache = {};
var countrySource = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        url: "http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson"
    })
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: countrySource,
        style: function (feature, resolution) {
            var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
            if (!styleCache[text]) {
                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#319FD3',
                        width: 1
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                        text: text,
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#000'
                        }),
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#fff',
                            width: 3
                        })
                    })
                })];
            }
            return styleCache[text];
        }
    });

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 5
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
                layer: 'osm'
            })
        }),
        vectorLayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: view
    });
```

3. Implement highlighting styles for country:

   var highlightStyleCache = {};
       var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
                   map: map,
                   style: function (feature, resolution) {
                       var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
                       if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
                           highlightStyleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                               stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                   color: '#f00',
                                   width: 1
                               }),
                               fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                   color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
                               }),
                               text: new ol.style.Text({
                                   font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                   text: text,
                                   fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                       color: '#000'
                                   }),
                                   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                       color: '#f00',
                                       width: 3
                                   })
                               })
                           })];
                       }
                       return highlightStyleCache[text];
                   }
               });

   4. Parse country names from loaded country data and fill selector options with it:

var highlightStyleCache = {};
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
    map: map,
    style: function (feature, resolution) {
        var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
        if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
            highlightStyleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#f00',
                    width: 1
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                    text: text,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#000'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#f00',
                        width: 3
                    })
                })
            })];
        }
        return highlightStyleCache[text];
    }
});

5. Zoom to and hightlight selected country:

   var selectFeatureInfo = function (featureId) {
       var features = countrySource.getFeatures();
                    var feature;
                   for (var f = 0; f < features.length; f++) {
                        feature = features[f];
                       if (feature.aa == featureId) {
                           var polygon = (feature.getGeometry());
                           var size = (map.getSize());
                           view.fitGeometry(
                           polygon,
                           size, {
                               padding: [170, 50, 30, 150]
                           });
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   if (feature !== highlight) {
                       if (highlight) {
                           featureOverlay.removeFeature(highlight);
                       }
                       if (feature) {
                           featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
                       }
                       highlight = feature;
                   }
               };

JSFiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/den367/bs97uLzf/4/)